# Бессмысленен – откуда пошло слово и почему нет женского рода?

Tags: словообразование, суффиксы, краткое-прилагательное

Существует слово **бессмысленен**, но почему тогда оно подчеркивается красным? Является ли оно кратким прилагательным? Почему у него не существует склонения в женском роде? Существуют ли еще подобные, строго «мужскородные» прилагательные?

Comment: "Бессмысленна"?

Comment: Да, похоже на то. Я почему-то думал, что должно быть "бессмысленена". Интересная разнородность у разных родов.

Comment: Вот, как мне кажется, интересная научная работа: https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/kratkie-prilagatelnye-na-en-enen-v-sovremennom-yazykovom-soznanii-i-problemy-ih-kodifikatsii-po-dannym-statisticheskogo-obsledovaniya#:~:text=%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%20%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%81)%3A,%2C%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%20%5B5%2C%20%D1%81. (Краткие прилагательные на -ен/-енен в современном языковом сознании...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, это краткое прилагательное. В женском роде одна ***е*** выпадает: *бессмысленна*.
Проблема возникает только в образовании кратких форм мужского рода прилагательных на ***-енный***.

Разные [словари](https://sanstv.ru/dict/%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) фиксируют *бессмысл**ен***.

> [**БЕССМЫСЛЕННЫЙ,**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x) -ая, -ое; -лен, -ленна, -ленно. <...> *Ваш протест бессмыслен.*

Хотя [предложения со словом «бессмысл**енен**»](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC/%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD), конечно, есть.

Вот что пишет [Грамота.ру](http://spravka.gramota.ru/lenta/news/8_3290):

> **Пожалуйста, ответьте на вопрос, который меня волнует уже 50 лет! *Ответствен или ответственен, искрен или искренен*?**
>
> Правильно: *ответствен и ответственен; искренен.*
>
> По отношению к кратким формам прилагательных мужского рода, которые кончаются на *-енный*, в полной мере применимо утверждение «Все новое – это хорошо забытое старое». Разнобой в рекомендациях насчет предпочтительности вариантов на *-ен* или *-енен* в свое время подробно был описан Д. Э. Розенталем. Он сделал вывод: «...путь развития форм на *-ен* и на *-енен* был таким: от более древней формы на *-ен*, восходящей к старославянскому языку, к форме на *-енен*, а затем возврат к форме на *-ен* в наши дни».
> <...>
> Таким образом, в современном языке у очень многих прилагательных есть варианты, где-то всё еще предпочтительна (или даже единственно верна) форма на *-енен*, но всё-таки общее направление движения – в сторону преобладания вариантов на *-ен.*